# How to place reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, recaptcha

This would be my registration form. What should i do if i were to add a reCAPTCHA form within it?

```
<form method="post" action="doregister.php" id="register">
```

Register

```
<div>
  <label for="username">Username</label><br/>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required" placeholder="Username"align="right" width="48" height="48"/>
</div> <br/>

<div>
      <label for="password">Password</label><br/>
  <input type="password"  id="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="Password"/>
</div> <br/>    

<br/>

<br/>
<input type="submit" id ="btnSubmit" value="Register"/>
```

Comment: You can add above the submit button

Comment: thats wat i wanna ask...how..=.=~~

Comment: read the captcha documentation and do like that

Answer (score 0):

developers.google.com has a very good documentation on how to use recaptcha with php:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is to use any of the available php libraries. Here is a friendly API to use called **[Securimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org)** There is a php script to include and few classes are available to produce captcha images and to validate them. Sample code to validate the input

```
include_once 'securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
  echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
  exit;
}
```

Here is the [quick start](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/)